# What Java frameworks are there for performing dynamic code loading over a network?

Tags: java, dynamic

I'm working with microservices a lot lately and thought it would be useful to be able to pass pieces of functionality between services without them needing a dependency on it before they are deployed.

Essentially I want to be able being able to inject new code into a microservice while it is running?

I din't want to re-invent the wheel, so wondered if anyone had made a framework for this already?

Thanks

Comment: take a look at [Java Compiler API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) or [Invoke Javac At Runtime](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/12/12/invoke-javac-at-runtime/)

Answer (score 1):

A [`URLClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) can load class files (optionally packaged in JAR files) from remote servers. You can then instantiate those classes through reflection, and use the resulting objects however you please.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into [OSGi](http://www.osgi.org/Main/HomePage), with the caveat that it can definitely be a little overwhelming to get up to speed. With OSGi you will be able to dynamically load Java components onto a running service.

Answer (score 0):

RMI, JNLP and JINI support loading code from remote. There are also some "agent" based research projects.

For Microsoervices I would however more look into the repository based code distribution, for example Apache Karaf and CXF distributed OSGi.